# Generating IDL entities using automake/Makefile.am

Tags: build-process, makefile, automake, idl, libtool

For those unfamiliar with IDL (interface description language), it abstracts data description for use across platforms (java, c, c++, etc). My project has dependencies Foo.c, Foo.h, FooHelper.c, and FooHelper.h which are generated from Foo.idl. How do I run an arbitrary command when Foo.idl changes, but still include Foo.c, FooHelper.c, in the build process?

My current attempts add a rule to the Makefile.am -- the hope is that the rule is copied over to the generated Makefile.

I have tried:

```
Foo.idl : Foo.idl
 ${the_generate_command}
```

and then added Foo.idl to my_program_SOURCES but it doesn't run the_generate_command when building.

I have had success generating from the IDL with

```
Foo.c Foo.h FooHelper.h FooHelper.c : Foo.idl
 ${the_generate_command}
```

But it won't add Foo.c, FooHelper.c to the compile process, so they're never built, just generated by the_generate_command!

All the code (including the idl) is in $PROJECT_DIR/src.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rq's answer is almost correct, but misses a couple of subtleties. Try this:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = myprogram
myprogram_SOURCES = Foo.c Foo.h FooHelper.h FooHelper.c $(OTHER_SOURCES)
BUILT_SOURCES = Foo.c Foo.h FooHelper.h FooHelper.c
EXTRA_DIST = Foo.idl
MAINTAINERCLEANFILES = Foo.c Foo.h FooHelper.h FooHelper.c

Foo.c: Foo.idl
    $(THE_GENERATE_COMMAND)

Foo.h FooHelper.h FooHelper.c: Foo.c
    @if test -f $@; then \
        touch $@; \
    else \
## Recover from the removal of $@
        rm -rf $<; \
        $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) $<; \
    fi
```

The additional rules to "generate" `Foo.h`, `FooHelper.h` and `FooHelper.c` from `Foo.c` ensure that parallel builds won't try and run `$(THE_GENERATE_COMMAND)` twice. It is an idiom detailed in [the Automake manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Multiple-Outputs.html#Multiple-Outputs) which will work for parallel builds. There is still a little fragility here: if the user removes (say) `FooHelper.h` and `FooHelper.c` and starts a parallel make, it may run the `$(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) $<` recovery part of the rule multiple times in parallel. As the manual says, this race can only going to happen if the user manually mutilates the build tree, and even then it's nothing a `make clean; make` cannot fix.

The `BUILT_SOURCES` line ensures that `Foo.c`, `Foo.h`, `FooHelper.h` and `FooHelper.c` are built before trying to build `myprogram` (see [this section](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Sources.html#index-BUILT_005fSOURCES-645) of the Automake manual to see why just adding them to `myprog_SOURCES` is insufficient). The `EXTRA_DIST` variable ensures that the `.idl` file will be captured by `make dist` ([reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Basics-of-Distribution.html#index-EXTRA_005fDIST-775)).

`MAINTAINERCLEANFILES` specifies additional files to delete when running `make maintainer-clean`; this is to comply with the [GNU Makefile Standards](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/standards/Standard-Targets.html#Standard-Targets). See also the variable's description in [the Automake manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Clean.html#index-MAINTAINERCLEANFILES-761).